iptables allowing outbound traffic when it should forbidden ... via loopback?
My iptables config is supposed to allow localhost traffic, allow ssh traffic (port 22), allow icmp traffic in both direction, and block everything else.
However, in practice outbound traffic still works just fine (e.g. wget google.com).
Something that I don't quite understand is that if I remove the localhost oubound allow rule (rule 1 in the OUTPUT chain), then outbound traffic is blocked correctly.
EDIT: There is a local DNS resolver setup (systemd-resolved), so disallowing localhost makes things fail at the DNS resolution stage. However, trying to wget the google IP directly (or 8.8.8.8) just causes a timeout, so I don't think that's the only thing going on here.
What the hell is going on?
Here is my config:
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 292 packets, 18733 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1       32  2560 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere
2     4657  582K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:22
3      615 22024 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 4 packets, 268 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        8   640 ACCEPT     all  --  any    lo      anywhere             anywhere
2     3771  597K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:22 state ESTABLISHED
3      520 17684 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

This is on a clean Ubuntu 24.04 install, with basically nothing else configured.

I figured it out, it's really dumb: it was using ipv6 and I had not configured the ipv6 tablers (via ip6tables) accordingly.
